# Missing header 'Authorization' 500 error even when Authorization present in request

Tags: ajax, header, authorization

I'm trying to make an AJAX POST request to a third party web service. Since I'm posting to an external resource I am using a php proxy because I do not own the service and cannot get them to implement CORS or JSONP.

The service uses basic authorization which I have tried to set in the AJAX request using the beforesend set request header and the ajaxsetup methods.

I can see the Authorization header set in the Request when I check it in the network tab in the chrome and firefox. But the server is returning a 500 error with a missing authorization exception.

Thanks for your time
Cheers.

I have pasted the response below

Apache Tomcat/7.0.22 - Error report

#### HTTP Status 500 -

**type** Exception report

**message**

**description** The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

**exception**

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvocationException: Failed to invoke handler method [public com.valuescentre.insight.api.model.BasicResponse com.valuescentre.insight.api.controller.PVAWebService.request(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,com.valuescentre.insight.api.model.PVARequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) throws java.lang.Exception]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Missing header 'Authorization' of type [java.lang.String]
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:656)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
```

**root cause**

```
org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvocationException: Failed to invoke handler method [public com.valuescentre.insight.api.model.BasicResponse com.valuescentre.insight.api.controller.PVAWebService.request(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,com.valuescentre.insight.api.model.PVARequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) throws java.lang.Exception]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Missing header 'Authorization' of type [java.lang.String]
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:181)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
```

**root cause**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Missing header 'Authorization' of type [java.lang.String]
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.raiseMissingHeaderException(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:784)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.resolveRequestHeader(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:554)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.resolveHandlerArguments(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:343)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:171)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
```

Answer (score 0):

I pin pointed the cause to the proxy.php script that I was using. I can't seem to find a decent php proxy script that works. 
Cheers